# Pycharm Nothing to show

Tags: python, pycharm

После обновлений любезно предложенных ОС, (linux Fedora), pycharm перестал показывать и открывать проект, пробовал удалить и установить заново, обновил все до чего смог додуматься
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Но ничего не помогло. Через терминал код запускается, все в порядке, проблема видимо только с pycharm

Comment: Закройте PyCharm, удалите папку .idea в проекте и откройте папку через PyCharm заново.

Comment: Не помогло. Так же не могу создать новый проект, терминал в пайчарме и все остальное там не работает.

Comment: Откатись на предыдущую версию. 2022.3 глючная до нельзя. У меня в ней jupyter перестал пакеты в проекте видеть. Жду следующей.

Comment: спасибо большое) прям очень выручил